# Find an alternative for norm2() and move_alloc() in Fortran 95

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I write code based on modern Fortran. For some reason, I want to modify it in a way that is compatible with the old version. Converting from the latest version to version 95 is desirable here. I have trouble with two intrinsic functions. "Mov_alloc" and "Norm2" are parts of these functions.
I want to know: are there any intrinsic functions for them in Fortran 95? Or, are there any external functions that do the same job precisely?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily implement `norm2()` yourself based on the definition. Some care must be taken if your numbers are so large that overflow is an issue. But the simplest version is as simple

```
norm2 = sqrt(sum(A**2))
```

There is no equivalent of `move_alloc()` in Fortran 95. You may need to use pointers instead of allocatable variables. You could implement your own version in C, but that would require many features from Fortran 2003-2018, so it makes little sense for you.

---

You can consider reallocating your arrays yourself and copying the data instead of doing `move_alloc()`:

```
   if (allocated(B)) deallocate(B)
   allocate(B(lbound(A,1):ubound(A,1)))
   B(:) = A
   deallocate(A)
```

However, it is not the same as `move_alloc()`.

Comment: Based on your answer, a combination of "pointer" and "allocate" can be done the "move_alloc" job. So, an external function can be written for "move_alloc". Is the last statement is correct?

Comment: No, it is not. You would have to change everything from `allocate` to `pointer`. Dirty tricks with external functions (or actually when lying in your interface blocks) do actually sometimes work, but are completely forbidden by the standard and at your own risk.

Comment: Consider, whether you actually really need the `move_alloc()`. Can't you just copy the values?

Comment: It works in a module. It copies and deallocates the variable. I think don't need a pointer. A combination of allocating and copy is needed.

Comment: If you know what is needed, why do you ask? Please see my previous comment: "
Consider, whether you actually really need the move_alloc(). Can't you just copy the values?" `move_alloc()` has a special purpose that on its own cannot be implemented in any other Fortran 95 way. Simply cannot. But you can of course do a sequence f copying, allocating and deallocating. That is not the same what `move_alloc()` does though. Be aware that we can't see your code.

Comment: You lack a square root in your first example. See here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/NORM2.html. This is indeed a quick solution. But it is not quite convenient. If the code is huge and there are many occurrences of `norm2` and the function is applied applied to vectors, matrices and higher rank entities, it is better to re-write it as a separate function. This is a lot of work. Maybe you can give some small advice  how to implement such function.

Comment: By the way, for some strange reason the `xlf` fortran compiler from IBM does not provide this function even in their implementation of the 2008 standard.

Comment: @yarchik Thank you for your correction. I do not see how it could be a lot of work. Just put it into a function, that's all. Unless you want to make sure it does not overflow. But I am not going to go into this.

Comment: Well, not too much work, but arrays can have different rank plus `sum` has second optional argument. :)

Comment: @yarchik. In F20018 one can use assumed rank. But a simple copy and paste into a generic function for different ranks and kinds in F95 is just mechanical work. As, for the dim argument or mask, I do not care about that here either.